# What's the naming convention in python for variable name already taken and occupied by system library

Tags: python, naming-conventions

Sometimes I need to use variable name like `max`, or `len`, but they are somehow occupied by the python library method. Should I instead just use `_max` or `max_`?

What is the conversion for these variable naming style?

Comment: make it more specific. if it's a maximum length, use `maxlen` or something like `max_length`. If it's the length of something, use `length`. Don't use weird underscores :P

Comment: underscores have implicit meaning in python, see https://hackernoon.com/understanding-the-underscore-of-python-309d1a029edc

Comment: The convention is to use a trailing underscore: `max_` or `len_`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no such convention, at least not in [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), what is mentioned in PEP 8 that may apply is the following:

> If a function argument's name clashes with a reserved keyword, it is generally better to append a single trailing underscore rather than use an abbreviation or spelling corruption. Thus class_ is better than clss. (Perhaps better is to avoid such clashes by using a synonym.)

Answer (score 1):

From [pep8 official documentation](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#overriding-principle):

> single_trailing_underscore_: used by convention to avoid conflicts with Python keyword, e.g.
>
> Tkinter.Toplevel(master, class_='ClassName')